# If statement of a disabled button in Java Script for Protractor tests

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have the following issue:

- I have a page where the "Save button" becomes clickable only when I enter a certain value inside a text filed.
- What I want to do is to check that if the Save button is disabled, then I need to enter some value in that text field.

What I thought is to have something like this:

```
if (save button is disabled){
   enter text inside the filed
   click save button
}
```

What I couldn't do is to store the value of the save button being disabled into a Boolean variable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute()` int his way:

```
var yourElement = element(by.id('foo')); //find by id, class or whatever you want
expect(yourElement.getAttribute('disabled')).toBe(true)
```

Docs [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute)

So to your purpose you can use something like this:

```js
if (yourElement.getAttribute('disabled')){
   enter text inside the filed
   click save button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution!

I wrote it like this:

```
        assertDisabled = function(){
            assertionsPage.assertAttribute(myProfilePage.saveButton,'disabled','true')
            return true
        }
        var value = assertDisabled()
        console.log(value)
        if (value==true){
            myProfilePage.pinCodeValue.sendKeys(1234)
        }
```

The assertAttribute does exactly what you said, but i thought it could be used across other tests.